# Handling submitting mentions in React Mentions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm using https://github.com/signavio/react-mentions for React Mentions, a facebook @mentions-like frontend feature where a user can mention another user in the comment box.

How does this Signavio comment box thing know that certain @user is selected when the comment is submitted? Is it built in?

Answer (score 1):

The [`onChange`](https://github.com/signavio/react-mentions#configuration) callback is invoked when the user changes the value in the mentions input. The submission logic is up to the developer to implement.

Comment: right, but what would be a great way to collect all mentioned users when they hit submit? Like will I have to iterate over the text and look for '@'?